# Optional chaining in Azure function with node 14.18.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm getting syntax errors with optional chaining while running an Azure function locally. Using Azure Functions Core Tools 4.0.3971 & Node 14.18.3:

> Worker was unable to load function foo: 'SyntaxError: Invalid or
> unexpected token'

It points to the dot in the optional chaining code as if the syntax is not supported:
`variable?.prop`

I have Node 14.18.3 installed on my machine, which I understand should support this. Wondering if there is something I could be missing in terms of telling the Azure function to use that Node version?

Comment: You're right that that version should have optional chaining, Node.js has had it (unflagged) [since v14.0.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be another module (CJS) causing the syntax error when trying to include the optional chaining.

Comment: Did you find a way to rectify the issue with CJS? I am also experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say is a syntax error in your code. I believe this happened to me before, and it is nothing on AFCT nor the AF configuration.

I believe it happened that I did a `require` wrongly or something along those lines.

Perhaps running eslint on it will help.

Comment: It works when I remove the question marks for the null checking and fails again when trying with a simple one line containing the optional chaining like the above - so it does appear to be some kind of issue dealing with the newer JS feature.